# Keyboard Differences Between Simulator and iDevice

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, ios-simulator

I have noticed a weird "bug" ,developing an app for ios7 . Having set keyboard style ,at UITextFields , like this  :

```
MyUITextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```

everything seems to be working as expected at simulator.

However, when app is running at every iDevice , the expected dot(.) symbol of keyboard , is replaced by comma . Is it a bug , or something that i didn't pay attention to ? If it isn't a bug , what change should be made ,considering the textfields keyboard type?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The character on that key is governed by the current locale so it depends on your device's locale. In some locales, a decimal separator is a comma and in others (US) it is a dot...

Try changing the locale on your device.

Comment: Can you be more spefic?Can i programmatically change locale or force somehow , keyboard show dot instead of comma?

Comment: What country is your iDevice set to? Set it to US and the "," will change to "." It is good to keep it that way since some international countries will expect a "," instead of a "." See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark to understand what each country expects (see section: examples of use)

Comment: Well, i don't want to change it from iDevice.This app is going to be published at app store .It is not a try out experiment. My country is using "Arabic numerals with decimal comma".

Comment: You can not change the locale programmatically... So I guess my question is correct and the only possible answer... I appreciate you setting it as such since there are no other solutions than the one I have provided (as far as I know)...

Comment: Ok finally i figured it out ,creating my own Keyboard!Thank you for your suggestion rkh :)